# Correct way to use FadeOut callbacks

Tags: jquery

What is the correct way to fadeout, and then fadeIn again?

Is it:

```
$("iframe#youtube").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","www.youtube.com/embed/"+data.url+"?rel=0&autoplay=1");
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Or:

```
$("iframe#youtube").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","www.youtube.com/embed/"+data.url+"?rel=0&autoplay=1");
}).fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("iframe#youtube").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","www.youtube.com/embed/"+data.url+"?rel=0&autoplay=1").fadeIn(500);
});
```

First before any change you need to fadeout and hide content. Made all changes and after that to display with fade in. That's it.

Comment: Thanks! I've never really understood how the jquery chain works.

Comment: Generaly is easy. jQuery have a lot of callbacks in functionality. When you figureout just fallow logic steps. Setup->Begin->End->Begin->End->etc.